# How the parent class properties get initialised without using super inside the child class?

Tags: javascript, class, prototypal-inheritance

```
class Book{
  constructor(title,year){
    this.title = title
    this.year = year
  }
  getDetails(){
    return `Book ${this.title} is written in ${this.year}`
  }
}
class Magazine extends Book{
  // constructor(title,year,month){
  //   super(title,year)
  //   this.month = month
  // }
  
  fullDetails(){
    console.log(this.getDetails());
  }
}
const newBook = new Magazine('xxx','2022')
newBook.fullDetails() //output : Book xxx is written in 2022
```

In the above code, Book is the parent class and the Magazine is the child class which extends from Book class. Then I have created an object for the child class by passing the values for the title and year. I have commented out the constructor function and the super method in the child class(Magazine) but still, the properties of the parent class properties(title, year) are initialized and I can get the output. Can anyone explain how this is possible without calling super in the child class? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't define a constructor in your child class, the parent constructor is automatically called. Only if you override it can you take control of what happens in it.

Try what follows, you'll see the constructor of the mother class is not called.

```
class Book{
  constructor(title,year){
    this.title = title
    this.year = year
  }
  getDetails(){
    return `Book ${this.title} is written in ${this.year}`
  }
}
class Magazine extends Book{
  constructor(title,year,month){
    // Do nothing
    console.log('constructor is overidden');

 }
  
  fullDetails(){
    console.log(this.getDetails());
  }
}
const newBook = new Magazine('xxx','2022')
newBook.fullDetails()
```

Comment: Thanks, letibelim. I have one more doubt.
`import classes from './User.module.css'
import { Component } from 'react'

class User extends Component {
  render() {
    return <li className={classes.user}>{this.props.name}</li>;
  }
}`
here we are not passing the props value to the parent React Component class by using super, but we are able to use this.props in the render method. So the same above principle applies here also?

Comment: Once again, the parent of User is a Component. So when React does its magic, it instantiates a User object (calling its constructor), which in this case is the Component constructor. User inherits as well all the properties of Component, and "props" is among them.

Comment: Thanks, Letibelim, now I understood the concept.

Comment: You're welcome. If you find my answer satisfactory, please mark it as the accepted answer !

Answer (score 0):

Since `Magazine` doesn't have its own constructor, it inherits the constructor of `Book`, so the `Book` properties get initialized.

You only need to call `super()` if the subclass has its own constructor, since that overrides the parent class constructor.

Comment: Thanks, Barmar. I have one more doubt.
`import classes from './User.module.css'
import { Component } from 'react'

class User extends Component {
  render() {
    return <li className={classes.user}>{this.props.name}</li>;
  }
}`
here we are not passing the props value to the parent React Component class by using super, but we are able to use this.props in the render method. So the same above principle applies here also?

Comment: The same principle. You haven't defined a constructor in the `User` class, so the `Component` constructor is used.